# How to copy word matching using grep command?

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 files: number1.txt and number2.txt.

## cat number1.txt

```
100 Jan
223 January
```

## cat number2.txt

```
621 Jan
589 January
```

I want to join both files to single file each line so the result file like this:

## cat result1.txt

```
100 Jan
621 Jan
```

## cat result2.txt

```
223 January
589 January
```

I try to run the bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

number=`cat number2.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sort | wc -l`
awk '{print $2}' number2.txt > month.txt

for i in $(seq 1 $number);
do
        user=`sed -n "$i p" month.txt`
        cat number1.txt | grep "^$user$" > result$i.txt
        cat number2.txt | grep "^$user$" >> result$i.txt
done
```

but the result files is empty file.
I think the problem in the code **grep "^$user$"** but I dont know how to solve it.

If I change to  **grep "$user"**, The result is not what I wanted and the result are like this:

## cat result1.txt

```
100 Jan
223 January
621 Jan
589 January
```

## cat result2.txt

```
223 January
589 January
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Why are you using `grep` instead of `awk`? `awk -v user="$user" '$2 == user' number1.txt` > result$i.txt`

Comment: @Barmar, because I think grep is more easy than awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `^` and `$` means that the line must consist only of `$user`, nothing else. If you want the lines **ending** in `$user`, do a

```
grep " $user$"
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Single `grep` will give you desired output:

```
$ grep -hv 'Jan$' number?.txt
223 January
589 January

$ grep -hv 'January$' number?.txt
100 Jan
621 Jan
```